# condicional en select que muestre sierto tipo de datos dependiendo si es nula o no una columna

Tags: oracle, select

Estoy utilizando en `case` para que me imprima dependiendo si la columna  `commission_pct` tiene datos nulos o no, por decir si la `commission_pct` tiene un dato nulo, solo imprima el `salary` y si no contiene datos nulos que me haga la operación matemática

```
select case mensual
       when commission_pct is null then (salary)
       when commission_pct is not null then (salary*commission_pct)
       from employees
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La construcción del `case` tal como describes debiera ser algo así:

```
select case 
          when commission_pct is null then (salary)
          else (salary*commission_pct)
       end
       from employees
```

Detalle:

- `Mensual` nada tiene que hacer en este `case`, solo se usaría para construcciones de este tipo: `case sexo when 'masculino' then when 'femenino' then when 'otro' then ... end`
- Como este es un `case` de dos condiciones, simplemente indicamos una de estas y resolvemos la siguiente con un `else`
- El `case` se debe finalizar con un `end`